# C++ algorithm loop fusion optimization

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

I find that occasionally in my code, I'll have a data structure and I want to get two or more values out of it, each of which can be extracted using a standard algorithm. The problem is, to use the standard algorithms means doing multiple loops through the data. Take the following example, where I have a `vector<int>` and want to get the sum, value of the first element above some threshold, and the total number of elements above that threshold:

```
constexpr auto GetValuesSTL(const std::vector<int>& testdata)
{
    constexpr auto value_above_threshold = [](const auto value) constexpr { return value > THRESHOLD; };
    constexpr auto optional_from_iterator = [](const auto it, const auto end) constexpr { return it != end ? std::make_optional(*it) : std::nullopt; };

    return std::make_tuple(
        std::accumulate(testdata.begin(), testdata.end(), 0L),
        optional_from_iterator(std::find_if(testdata.begin(), testdata.end(), value_above_threshold), testdata.end()),
        std::count_if(testdata.begin(), testdata.end(), value_above_threshold) );
}
```

but I can write this more efficiently as a raw loop:

```
constexpr auto GetValuesRawLoop(const std::vector<int>& testdata)
{
    auto sum = 0L;
    std::optional<int> first_above_threshold = std::nullopt;
    auto num_above_threshold = 0;

    auto it = testdata.begin();
    for (; it != testdata.end(); ++it)
    {
        const auto value = *it;

        if (value > THRESHOLD)
        {
            first_above_threshold = value;
            break;
        }

        sum += value;
    }
    for (; it != testdata.end(); ++it)
    {
        const auto value = *it;

        sum += value;

        if (value > THRESHOLD)
        {
            ++num_above_threshold;
        }
    }

    return std::make_tuple( sum, first_above_threshold, num_above_threshold );
}
```

I was hoping that the compiler would be able to fuse the algorithm calls into a single loop, since it has enough info to know that the vector isn't being modified, but profiling these two functions on various length vectors of randomly generated ints (compiled with `g++-9 -O3`) shows that the STL version of the function consistently takes about 2-2.5x times as long as the raw loop, exactly as you'd expect without loop fusion.

Is there a good reason the compiler can't/doesn't apply this optimisation? Is there some sort of assumption required to be able to fuse the loops that the compiler isn't allowed to make? Or is it a fundamentally difficult thing to detect and apply? Is there an alternative way to write it that could be as efficient as the raw loop and as expressive as the algorithm version?

Answer (score 0):

I am just going to answer the last part of your question:

> Is there an alternative way to write it that could be as efficient as
>   the raw loop and as expressive as the algorithm version?

Depending on what you consider to be "expressive", using a single std::accumulate may work like this:

```
constexpr auto GetValuesACC(const std::vector<int>& testdata)
    auto accumulator = [](std::tuple<int, std::optional<int>, int> init, int val) {
        return std::make_tuple(
            std::get<0>(init) + val, 
            std::get<1>(init).has_value() ? std::get<1>(init) : 
                (val > THRESHOLD ? std::make_optional(val) : std::nullopt),
            std::get<2>(init) + int(val > THRESHOLD));
};

    return std::accumulate(testdata.begin(), testdata.end(),
        std::make_tuple(0, std::nullopt, 0), accumulator);
}
```

This code implements an accumulator that maintains a tuple containing:

- sum of elements so far
- first above thresdhold seen so far -or- nullopt
- above threshold count so far

*Note*: I have not benchmarked the performance of this algorithm vs. your original version, or the raw loop, because the outcome will vary based on your hardware and exact compiler. However, this should be equivalent to a single hand-written loop.

**Edit**: I did some benchmarks locally...

- Hardware: MacOS, 1.8GHz Intel Core i5
- Compiler: LLVM 10, x86_64, --std=c++17, -O3
- Test used 3 runs with 10 iterations each, on input of 5x10^7 element vectors, containing sequential integers (std::iota), with THRESHOLD=5.
- Subtracted time to initialize the vectors (~1s).
- Data recorded using the 'user' output of the 'time' command, and all values are in seconds and sorted in ascending order.

  GetValuesRawLoop: 3.7, 4.0, 4.2
  GetValuesSTL:     4.4, 4.5, 4.6
  GetValuesACC:     78s (only did one run)

Summary so far:

- No significant difference between `GetValuesRawLoop` and `GetValuesSTL` *in my environment*.
- `GetValuesACC` is an order-of-magnitude slower.

Following hint from @John Ilacqua about `std::optional` being slow, I re-wrote all 3 algorithms using plain `int` and using `THRESHOLD` as the guard value to mean "there is no value above threshold".

Example of `GetValuesACC` without optional:

```
auto GetValuesACC2(const std::vector<int>& testdata)
{
    auto accumulator = [](const std::tuple<int, int, int>& init, int val) {
        return std::make_tuple(
            std::get<0>(init) + val, 
            std::get<1>(init) > THRESHOLD ? std::get<1>(init) : 
                (val > THRESHOLD ? val : THRESHOLD),
            std::get<2>(init) + int(val > THRESHOLD));
    };

    return std::accumulate(testdata.begin(), testdata.end(),
        std::make_tuple(0, THRESHOLD, 0), accumulator);
}
```

New results:

```
GetValuesRawLoop2: 0.3, 0.3, 0.6
GetValuesSTL2:     4.4, 4.4, 4.5
GetValuesACC2:     1.7, 1.8, 1.9
```

New summary:

- the implementation of optional in my version of LLVM is slow in this context

  - but doesn't really affect GetValuesSTL
- single accumulator is faster than 3 loops, but slower than raw loops

As always, "your mileage may vary!" These results underscore why it is important to profile in real-world usage before trying to optimize.

Comment: I actually already had something very similar I had written for comparison. It performs significantly worse than both of the other options, I believe because of the many redundant calls to `optional::has_value` (which is why my raw loop has the double loop - if I write it as a single loop those redundant branches have a massive performance impact).

Comment: @JohnIlacqua I tried some benchmarks and added a version without std::optional. So far your theory holds - that two manual loops is more efficient. If I can get gprof/pprof working, I'll try to see why GetValuesACC2 is still slower than GetRawLoop2.

Comment: interesting about `std::optional` being that slow - I had assumed it was just the additional branch. How does using random ints instead of sequential ones change the benchmark? The sum element of the tuple should probably be a `long `, to avoid overflow.